# my android device not detecting on visual studio 2015 for xamarin forms

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin forms with basic code. My honor 7x mobile device is not detecting on visual studio 2015. I disable the Use Shared Runtime and Use Fast Deployment. And also enable "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" and "INTERNET".
I am using Microsoft Windows 8.1 pro.
In device manager shows like below image:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1pOR.png)

Anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/set-up-device-for-development

Comment: Sorry for the delay reply. Thanks for your help Jason. Finally i update the honor hisuite software on my PC and it works fine now.